# Getting data in appropriate format

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which contains two column.

```
 Agency Code   MCI Numb
----------------------------
      a            1234 
      a            12345
      b            11
```

I need to write a query in SQl so that it will give data in following format.

```
< AgencyCode>
    <ID>a</ID>
    <MCI_NUMB>1234</MCI_NUMB>
    <MCI_NUMB>12345</MCI_NUMB>
</AgencyCode>
< AgencyCode>
    <ID>b</ID>
    <MCI_NUMB>11</MCI_NUMB>
</AgencyCode>
```

Comment: mySQL and SQL Server are NOT the same thing.  I'm assuming you want SQL Server, but...

Comment: but what else would i call tsql that *i* wrote?? ;)

Comment: yes i  want in sql server...

Comment: The easiest way to accomplish this is with an application written in .net or ColdFusion or something like that.  This app would get the data using a very simple query, and then generate the xml.  Also, once the xml is generated, I assume you want to do something with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use `FOR XML` / `XPATH` queries.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT ID
     , CAST(MCI_Numb AS xml).query('/') AS MCI_Numbs
  FROM(SELECT DISTINCT ID
                     , (SELECT MCI_Numb
                          FROM myTable
                          WHERE ID = T.ID
                          FOR XML PATH(''))AS MCI_Numb
         FROM myTable AS T)AS T2
  FOR XML PATH ('AgencyCode');
```

Take a look at this [link](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/manipulating-xml-data-in-sql-server/): It explains in detail how to manipulate the sql server into xml and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to take a look at :

FOR XML: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)

and

PIVOT: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)

The first will allow you to return xml, the second will allow you to pivot your data